# Script for sending whatsapp to number + trimming

Tags: autohotkey

I created a script that uses whatsapp api, it takes selected/clipboard number and builds the URL from there. I managed to make that work ( i'm new to AH ) but I'm not being able to trim spaces ( which I assumed it should be easy) . This is my script so far

```
{
  Send, ^c
  Sleep 50
  wspNumber := Trim(clipboard)
  Run, https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%wspNumber%
}
```

If the number is something like this 11111111 works perfectly but it doesnt trim when i have something like 111 111 111.

Comment: **Trim** removes any space characters from the start and end of the given string. You should use some kind of **Replace** script

Answer (score 0):

```
  Send, ^c   ; Copy selected content
  Sleep 50   ; Wait 50ms
  wspNumber := RegExReplace(clipboard, "\D")   ; Remove anything that isn't number, and save in the var "wspNumber"
  Run, https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=%wspNumber%   ; Run the url with the var
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: @TomasBuzeta You're welcome! If the answer helped you, consider marking it as helpful so it may be useful for other users as well.